# Configure Windows 10 start menu for all users, force no tiles (zero tiles)

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, tiles

Need to configure a windows 10 with no tiles, zero, nothing. 
Delete those "life at a glance" and "play and explore" default tiles. And that the users can't edit that layout.

For all users. well, only for non-administrators users, but that I already figured out with the "management console" gpedit.msc and a custom .msc file.

The strange issue here is that Exporting a layout and then forcing it for all users work.
But it doesn't work if the exported layout has no/zero tiles! crazy! It generates an invalid file it seems, keep reading.

this is how I exported the layout

```
export-startlayout -path 0-tiles.xml
```

and then enforcing it in
gpedit.msc - user configuration - administratrive templates - start menu and task bar -- start menu layout   ( <-- I'm translating those items from a spanish windows, don't take them 100% literal )

only results in having all the default tiles, all "life at a glance" "play and explore" tiles!

Why it fails to accept zero tiles?
How can that be forced?

Also experimented with file
c:\users\default\appdata\local\microsoft\windows\shell\defaultlayouts.xml

1) I emptied *all* the tiles on that file (edited the file by hand)
2) also deled the file

in both cases you get 3 default icons (windows store, etc, etc)

...Also tried importing the 0-tiles file, that ends on error:

```
import-startlayout -layoutpath 0-tiles.xml -mountpath c:\
```

that command works with files with at least one tile, but gives error with the zero tile generated .xml file:

```
import-startlayout : the file 0-tiles.xml is not a valid  design file
```

so it seems to generate an invalid file

Where is the tile configuration beign stored for each user? Maybe editing  that directly works.

Comment: Why don't you just use third-party software to change the start-menu, StartIsBack++, has no tiles.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation!

Customization works, this is not complicated, when you edit a standard start menu you get a 0 tile menu with no problem, windows tools then fail to export or import a valid xml file or some other error :(

   My boss didn't ask me for a win7 start menu, just for a standard win10 start menu with no tiles.

Comment: So remove the tiles,  what tiles are pinned, are configurable.